# How can I convert this Mysql query into active record query in Yii2

Tags: yii2, mysql-workbench

```
Select * 
from po_table 
WHERE sender_uid = "User Input" and po_no IN (
   Select po_no WHERE receiver_uid = login_rec_uid
);
```

Comment: Add your models pls :)

Comment: We are trying with the following model query:  $subQuery = ModelName::find()->select('po_no')->where('receiver_uid' => login_rec_uid);
$query = ModelName::find()->andwhere([' in', 'po_no', $subQuery]);
$models = $query;

Answer (score 0):

Try using find() from activeRecord class

e.x:

$senderid = Sender::find()->where(['id' => $userInputID])->one();

source: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne()-detail